# Is it possible to use module pattern for more objects

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, private

```
var modularpattern = (function () {
var sum = 0;

return {
    add: function () {
        sum = sum + 1;
        return sum;
    },

  }
} ());
var c = modularpattern;
c.add();   // 1
var d = modularpattern;
d.add();   //  2 but I want to be 1
 console.log(modularpattern.add());    // alerts: 3
```

Is it possible to have more objects not only one? I want to have private fields but at the same time also having more that just one object?

Comment: how should the result look like?

Comment: @Nina Scholz c.add ==>1 d.add ==>1 console.log(..) ==>1

Comment: it makes the problem not clear.

Comment: @Nina Scholz for each new variable I create (c, d) the sum should be 0 at the beginning, but sum stays never changes. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's easily possible by dropping the IIFE invocation to get a normal function instead. Only it's called *factory pattern* then, no longer *module*.

```
function factory() {
    var sum = 0;
    return {
        add: function () {
            sum = sum + 1;
            return sum;
        }
    }
}
var c = factory();
c.add();   // 1
var d = factory();
d.add();   // 1
console.log(c.add()); // logs: 2
```

Comment: is that the only way. Does a way exist where I use IIFE invocation?

Comment: I cannot imagine a way where you'd use an IIFE that's not unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the module pattern to create a factory which uses the module pattern to create more objects. Using your original example, it would look something like this:

```
var moduleFactory = (function() {
  return {
    create: function() {
      return (function() {
        var sum = 0;
        return {
          add: function() {
            sum = sum + 1;
            return sum;
          }
        }
      })();
    }
  }
}
)();

var c = moduleFactory.create();
console.log(c.add()); //1
var d = moduleFactory.create();
console.log(d.add()); //1
```

Comment: Wow, seriously?